# How to define function which changes at certain condition

Tags: function-construction, conditional, piecewise

```
T1[z_, t_] = (A1 Cos[z] + B1 Sin[z]) Exp[t];(*from z=0 to z=a=1*)
T2[z_, t_] = (A2 Cos[z] + B2 Sin[z]) Exp[t];(*from z=a=1 to z=b=2*)
T3[z_, t_] = (A3 Cos[z] + B3 Sin[z]) Exp[t];(*from z=b=2 to z=c=3*)
Interval1 = [0, a];
Interval2 = [a, b];
Interval3 = [b, c];
T[z_,t_]=...
```

This is basic definition of my problem. Is have temperature function depending on time t and location z.

I have 1D problem (z) where i have three different layers and in each layer, temperature has its own function T1,T2,T3. A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3 are known (random) constants (you can make them up for this example)
[image: Graphic presentation of the problem]

For each area/interval temperature changes by its presented function T1,T2,T3.

Is it possible to define globally mora general temperature function `T[z_,t_]` where you can define that on certain/given interval takes form of the predefined `Ti[z,t]` function, for instance when z=[0,a], `T[z,t]=T1[z,t]`, when z is in [a,b],then `T[z,t]=T2[z,t]` and so on...

Comment: Sounds like you might want `Piecewise`.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
T[z_,t_]:=
  Which[
    z<0,BadT[z,t],
    z<a,T1[z,t],
    z<b,T2[z,t],
    z<c,T3[z,t],
    True,BadT[z,t]]
```

Alternatively, you can add conditions:

```
T[z_, t_] := (A1 Cos[z] + B1 Sin[z]) Exp[t] /; 0 <= z < a;
T[z_, t_] := (A2 Cos[z] + B2 Sin[z]) Exp[t] /; a <= z < b;
T[z_, t_] := (A3 Cos[z] + B3 Sin[z]) Exp[t] /; b <= z < c;
```

Or another option with Piecewise:

```
T = 
  Piecewise[
    {{T1[z, t], 0 <= z < a}, 
     {T2[z, t], a <= z < b},
     {T3[z, t], b <= z < c}, 
     {BadT[z, t], True}}]
```

In this latter case, you would use it something like this:

```
Plot3D[T, {z, 0, c}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

(For all of these, I'm assuming that `a`, `b`, `c`, `A1`, `B1`, etc have all been defined)

Comment: `Which[]` certainly works, but I would upvote your answer if you show the `Piecewise[]` version as well. ;)

Comment: Wouldn’t Piecewise introduce the issue of coordinating on the name of the formal argument? That is not something that seems relevant to the original question.

Comment: I mean, you could write it as `Piecewise[{{T1[z, t], 0 <= z < a}, (* other stuff *)}, BadT[z, t]]` (careful with the inequalities, tho) and it should still work, with the added bonus that it's guaranteed to play nice with calculus functionality.

Comment: For the lazy :), `Which[z < 0, BadT[z, t], z < a, T1[z, t], z < b, T2[z, t], z < c, T3[z, t], True, BadT[z, t]] // PiecewiseExpand`.  (Execute before `T1` etc. are defined, though.)

Comment: There used to be advantages to `Piecewise` in a mathematical function over other programmatically equivalent formulations. They worked better with solvers. Nowadays, most or all solvers seem to apply `PiecewiseExpand` internally. E.g., try `Integrate[Which[...], z]`